# NO me funciona except de python

Tags: python, excepciones

## !/usr/local/bin/python3

Escribe una función iterativa **`iterPower​ ​(base,​ ​exp)`**​ que calcula el exponencial `baseexp` simplemente usando multiplicación sucesiva.

Por ejemplo, **`iterPower (base, exp)`** debe calcular `baseexp` multiplicando `base` por sí mismo `exp` veces.

Esta función debe tomar dos valores - `base` puede ser un float o un número entero; `exp` será un número entero ≥ 0. Debe devolver un valor numérico. 
El código debe ser iterativo - el uso
del operador ** no está permitido

`def iterPower(base, exp):` Eleva un numero entero o decimal a un numero entero, 
Devuelve un número real, resultado de la potencia entre dos números.

Parámetros:

```
`base` -- Puede ser entero o decimal
`exp`  -- Debe de ser entero y mayor a 0
```

Excepciones:
    Si los parámetros no son los esperados, devolverá un error avisando de ello

```
#Se crea el controlador de excepciones
try:
    #Para que exp no sea string se pasa a entero
    exp= int(exp)
    #Para que base no sea string se pasa a int o float, segun sea uno u otro
    if base.count(".")==0:
        base= int(base)
    else:
        base= float(base)
    #Si el exponente es menor a 0 lanza una excepcion persoanlizada
    if exp<0:
        raise ValueError("El exponente no puede ser menor a 0")
    #Se crea el total = 1 ya que 1 es el valor nulo en multiplicaciones
    total=1
    i=0
    #Realiza el bucle exp veces, por cada recorrido se multiplica un num a si mismo
    for i in range(int(exp)):
        total= base*total
    return total

except ValueError as mensaje: 
    #Imprime la excepcion personalizada
    print(mensaje)
except:
    print("No se han insertado bien los parámetros")
```

## Se ejecuta el programa demandando valores

```
print("\n\n***Programa para calcular las potencias de un número***\n")
base= input("Inserte la base: ")
exp= input("Insere el exponente: ")
```

## Se llama a la funcion

```
resultado= iterPower(base,exp)

print("El resultado es: "+str(resultado))
```

Tengo que hacer el siguiente ejercicio, todo va bien, hasta que veo que no recoge la excepción general, es decir, si no inserto bien los parámetros salta un error y no lo recoge la excepción, funciona la personalizada, pero esa no ,he observado que si quito la personalizada del **`ValueError`**, funciona la general, gracias de antemano.

Comment: ¿Y que prueba has hecho? ¿Con que valores te falla? He hecho algunas pruebas y no puedo reproducir el problema

Answer (score 1):

puedes intentar con esto:

```
try:
   #code
except ValueError as mensaje:
    #catpura un error de valor
    print(mensaje)
except Exception as e:
    print("cualquier error");
else:
    # si no ocurren errores de ningun tipo valor
   print("exitoso!")
finally:
    # si ocurre o no error se imprime
   print("operacion realizada!")
```

debes ir de la mas especifica a las mas globales!